# Implement a horizontal ray and vertical line with the lable like the tool in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have been wondering if its possible to adjust the lable like in the picture. The special feature i need for the horizontal lable is that if i move the chart the lable stays at one point on my screen just like if u would draw it but i couldnt figure that out. I also want to put the label like how its shown in the screenshot but im not sure if thats possible. I just recently started with pinescript so i dont know much yet.

[this is the example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gidOJ.png)

rn i have them at a set distance from the candle its drawn from but that just doesnt look good.